# Mailgun 404 error with Pythonanywhere

Tags: django, mailgun, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to use mailgun in my Django project hosted on Pythonanywhere.

In my WSGI file, I have:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_MAILGUN_SERVER_NAME'] = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxnumbersomething.mailgun.org/messages'
os.environ['DJANGO_MAILGUN_API_KEY'] ='mykey'
```

and my settings are:

```
# EMAIL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env('DJANGO_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL',
                         default='Apitrak <noreply@apitrak.com>')
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_mailgun.MailgunBackend'
MAILGUN_ACCESS_KEY = env('DJANGO_MAILGUN_API_KEY')
MAILGUN_SERVER_NAME = env('DJANGO_MAILGUN_SERVER_NAME')
```

When my app fire an email (for example at signup), I have a 404 error:

```
MailgunAPIError at /accounts/email/

<Response [404]>

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    https://vincentle.pythonanywhere.com/accounts/email/
Django Version:     1.8.6
Exception Type:     MailgunAPIError
Exception Value:    

<Response [404]>

Exception Location:     /home/vincentle/.virtualenvs/apitrak/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_mailgun.py in _send, line 154
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:     3.4.0
Python Path:    

['/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/vincentle/.virtualenvs/apitrak/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/vincentle/.virtualenvs/apitrak/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/vincentle/.virtualenvs/apitrak/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/vincentle/.virtualenvs/apitrak/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/vincentle/apitrak']

Server time:    Tue, 17 Nov 2015 16:02:28 +0100
```

I've tried a curl in the virtualenv of my WebApp:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-NUMBERS' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/NUMBERS.mailgun.org/messages -F from='Excited User <excited@samples.mailgun.org>' -F to='vincent@vincentle.fr'  -F subject='Hello'  -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

And this works OK.

Comment: Can you show us the code where fire the Mail ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting `DJANGO_MAILGUN_SERVER_NAME` should be a domain name, not a url.

Try the following:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_MAILGUN_SERVER_NAME'] = '<sandboxnumbersomething>.mailgun.org'
```

From the [readme](https://github.com/BradWhittington/django-mailgun):

> Replace `SERVER-NAME` with the last part of your "API Base URL" (e.g. `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<your_server_name>`), also found in your Mailgun account details.